# Custom font is not working with itextrenderer in java

Tags: java, css, flying-saucer

I have embedded my custom fonts in html with @font-face. This working with all browser but when I am trying to convert it to pdf through itextrender in java custom font is not working anymore its taking default fonts like Arial.

**css code**:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: Subaru-Medium;
        src: url('fonts/Subaru-Medium.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
        src: url('fonts/Subaru-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
             url('fonts/Subaru-Medium.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
             url('fonts/Subaru-Medium.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
        }
```

**java code**:

```
public static void writePDF(String HTMLfileName, String PDFFileName, String WhereToSave,String fontDirectory)
    {
        try
        {
            String url = new File(HTMLfileName).toURI().toURL().toString();
            String outputFile = WhereToSave+PDFFileName;
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            ITextFontResolver fontResolver=renderer.getFontResolver();
                  fontResolver.addFont("C:\\Users\\benay.debnath\\Desktop\\htmltemplate\\fonts\\Subaru-Medium.ttf", true);

                // fontResolver.addFontDirectory(fontDirectory, true);
                SharedContext scontext=renderer.getSharedContext();
                // scontext.setDPI(72);
                scontext.setDotsPerPixel(12);
                renderer.setDocument(url);
                renderer.layout();
                renderer.createPDF(os);
                os.close();
                System.out.println("status:$:true^#^message:$:PDF    Genarated^#^fileName:$:"+outputFile);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("status:$:false^#^message:$:"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Any one can help me to find what I am doing wrong? help much appreciated.

Comment: I have same Problem. I am working in grails and using rendering plugin. I am using css to import font but in pdf I am getting expected result. have you some idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has resolved, the problem was in css I mentioned font-family:"Subaru-Medium" in font file(.ttf) font name was "Subaru Medium" so it was not working. Now its working fine :)

Comment: If it's one, please [accept your answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: Comparing the actual "Font Name" property and "font-family" in CSS was the decisive hint. These values should be identical... This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure that below font has been installed in your system if not then install font and add following line in your code.

```
public static void writePDF(String HTMLfileName, String PDFFileName, String WhereToSave,String fontDirectory)
    {
        try
        {
            String url = new File(HTMLfileName).toURI().toURL().toString();
            String outputFile = WhereToSave+PDFFileName;
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf","UTF-8",BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

                // fontResolver.addFontDirectory(fontDirectory, true);
                SharedContext scontext=renderer.getSharedContext();
                // scontext.setDPI(72);
                scontext.setDotsPerPixel(12);
                renderer.setDocument(url);
                renderer.layout();
                renderer.createPDF(os);
                os.close();
                System.out.println("status:$:true^#^message:$:PDF    Genarated^#^fileName:$:"+outputFile);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("status:$:false^#^message:$:"+e.getMessage());
        }
```

I was also facing same problem i have resolved using above solution. hope this will be useful for you :)